# Phonegap Build: No Android xhdpi Icon, uses default

Tags: android, cordova, icons

I've tryed some time around but got still the default Icon for xhdpi Android Devices.
If I took a look into the apk the problem is that in res/drawable and res/drawable-xhdpi the Phonegap Default Icon is still used.

My config.xml:

```
<icon src="icon.png" width="96" height="96" />
<icon src="icons/ios/icon.png" width="57" height="57" />
<icon src="icons/ios/icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />
<icon src="icons/ios/icon_at_2x.png" width="114" height="114" />
<icon src="icons/android/ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" width="36" height="36"/>
<icon src="icons/android/mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" width="48" height="48"/>
<icon src="icons/android/hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" width="72" height="72"/>
<icon src="icons/android/xdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" width="96" height="96"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

well actually phonegap still have problems to load xhdpi icons. (state 10/04/14)

working workaround is:

```
<!-- ldpi --> 
<icon src="resources/images/icons/android/icon-36.png"  gap:platform="android" width="36" height="36" />
<icon src="resources/images/icons/android/icon-48.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" /> 
<!-- mdpi --> 
<icon src="resources/images/icons/android/icon-48.png"  gap:platform="android" width="48" height="48" /> 
<icon src="resources/images/icons/android/icon-72.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" /> 
<!-- hdpi --> 
<icon src="resources/images/icons/android/icon-72.png"  gap:platform="android" width="72" height="72" /> 
<icon src="resources/images/icons/android/icon-96.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" /> 
<!-- xhdpi --> 
<icon src="resources/images/icons/android/icon-96.png"  gap:platform="android" width="96" height="96" /> 
<icon src="resources/images/icons/android/icon-114.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to be attempted to wrong file paths (try `cordova prepare android --verbose` and look for errors). Then set up your files as follows:

Icon:

```
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" width="36" height="36" src="www/assets/images/icon/android/ic_launcher_ldpi.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" width="48" height="48" src="www/assets/images/icon/android/ic_launcher_mdpi.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" width="72" height="72" src="www/assets/images/icon/android/ic_launcher_hdpi.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" width="96" height="96" src="www/assets/images/icon/android/ic_launcher_xhdpi.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:density="xxhdpi" width="114" height="114" src="www/assets/images/icon/android/ic_launcher_xxhdpi.png" />
```

Splash:

```
<splash gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" src="www/assets/images/splash/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
<splash gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" src="www/assets/images/splash/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
<splash gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" src="www/assets/images/splash/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
<splash gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" src="www/assets/images/splash/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
<splash gap:platform="android" gap:density="xxhdpi" src="www/assets/images/splash/android/screen-xxhdpi-portrait.png" />
```

**Note:** It's working on phonegap@5.1.1 / cordova@5.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently fixed as of 17 August: https://github.com/phonegap/build/issues/9

Half works for me, there is a better icon displayed but seems to be using hdpi icon?